# Erro com pagination e codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Ao clicar no link da página o mesmo me retorna um NOT FOUND.

```
    <div class="scroll">
<table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><b>Nome</b></th>
            <th><b>Email</b></th>
            <td><b>Telefone</b></td>
            <td><b>Cidade</b></td>
            <td><b>PR</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($results as $data) : ?>
        <td><?= $data->nomeCliente ?></td>
        <td><?= $data->emailCliente ?></td>
        <td><?= $data->telefoneCliente ?></td>
        <td><?= $data->cidadeCliente ?></td>
        <td><?= $data->estadoCliente ?></td>            
        <td>
            <a ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" title="Apagar" onclick="modalDelete()"></i></a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <a href="index.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Editar".></i></a>
        </td>

        <td>
           <a href="index.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" title="Visualizar"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<center>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a><?php echo $links; ?></a></li>
    <ul>
</center>
</div>
```

Aqui esta o CONTROLLER

```
public function consultaClientes() {
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    $this->load->model("Cliente/Clientes_Model");
    $config["base_url"] = base_url('index.php/Cliente/');
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Clientes_Model->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 5;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = round($choice);

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->Clientes_Model
        ->fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $this->load->view("menu");
    $this->load->view("Cliente/Clientes", $data);
}
```

Aqui o MODEL

```
public function record_count() {
        return $this->db->count_all("cliente");
    }


    public function fetch_countries($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get("cliente");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Ainda existe uma rota configurada.

```
$route['Cliente'] = 'Cliente/Clientes/consultaClientes';
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece um roteamento incorreto. Quando o usuário digitar:

`www.seu-site.com.br/cliente/`

Ele será (virtualmente) levadado para:

`www.seu-site.com.br/cliente/clientes/consultaClientes`

Ou seja, para o método `clientes()` da classe `Cliente`, passando como parâmetros a string `consultaCliente`. Porém, provavelmente **não existe um método** `clientes($string)` na sua classe `Cliente`, também não faz sentido a string estática `'consultaClientes'`.

Penso que se a intenção é definir como o comportamento padrão da classe `Cliente` a visualização dos clientes, deveria se excluir o roteamento e implementar as ações dentro do método chamado `index()` na classe. Este é o método que automaticamente é invocado quando se requisita algo assim:

`www.seu-site.com.br/cliente`